# Subversion repository has a small file size compared to working copy?

Tags: svn, version-control, repository

I'm using the Versions application on a Mac to handle an SVN repository for my files. My working copy is around 6 MB, yet my repository is only 1.4 MB, and I am holding five revisions in the repository!

How can this be?

Comment: Compression might explain it, but I honestly don't know. 75% compression isn't unheard of for pure text.

Comment: (Note, it is actually around 75% because SVN only holds changes, not full copies of each revision))

Answer (score 19, accepted):

SVN compresses one version of your code the differences between each version. That is why it does not take much space.

> To keep the repository small,
>   Subversion uses deltification (or
>   deltified storage) within the
>   repository itself. Deltification
>   involves encoding the representation
>   of a chunk of data as a collection of
>   differences against some other chunk
>   of data. If the two pieces of data are
>   very similar, this deltification
>   results in storage savings for the
>   deltified chunk—rather than taking up
>   space equal to the size of the
>   original data, it takes up only enough
>   space to say, “I look just like this
>   other piece of data over here, except
>   for the following couple of changes.”
>   The result is that most of the
>   repository data that tends to be
>   bulky—namely, the contents of
>   versioned files—is stored at a much
>   smaller size than the original
>   full-text representation of that data.
>   And for repositories created with
>   Subversion 1.4 or later, the space
>   savings are even better—now those
>   full-text representations of file
>   contents are themselves compressed.

More detail can be found [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.diskspace.deltas)

Answer (score 9):

Nawaman's answer already explained that the data in the repository is compacted quite efficiently.

The other half of the story is that subversion keeps a [pristine copy](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.developer.insidewc.html) of each file inside the `.svn` folders of your working copy. This enables subversion to handle `svn status` or `svn diff` commands without needing to contact the repository server, but it **doubles the size of your working copy**.

Answer (score 5):

Your working copy normally contains a lot of additional temporary files such as object code and precompiled headers that are not required to be revision controlled. I guess if you clean the working copy, or make a new checkout it will be much smaller.

Comment: This is true, but for the reasons explained by Nawaman and wcoenen, even a newly checked out clean working copy with no generated files (such as precompiled headers and object code) may be significantly larger than the repository: the working copy has two copies of each file uncompressed (working and pristine), while the repository has 1 compressed copy of each file + deltafied changes (which can be very small if the changes were localized).

Answer (score 2):

Here are few reasons I can think of
- svn stores your revisions as changesets and not versioned files.
- svn stores data in its backend(FSFS/BDB) which has some compression techniques which reduces the size. If the repository has more text based files the more the compression is hence can expect a drastic decrease in size.
- To support few commands(like svn info, diff, etc) without network connection (also to have faster results) svn maintains some extra information in the .svn dirs. The extra information includes a copy of the whole working copy.